# Nested dict to object with default value

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I am using `dataclasses` + `dataclasses_json` to implement my web api.

My application will decode the request from dict to object, I hope that the object can still be generated without every field is fill, and fill the empty filed with default value.

This is my likely code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass
class Glasses:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int

@dataclass
class Tshirt:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class People:
    Name : str = 'James'
    Age : int = 25
    Glasses: Glasses = Glasses('black', 'M', 2500)
    Tshirt: Tshirt = Tshirt('black', 'XL', 500)

p = {
    'Name': 'Gino',
    'Age': 20,
    'Glasses': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    },
    'Tshirt': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    }
}

a = People.from_dict(p)
print(a)
```

and I will get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\People.py", line 39, in <module>
    a = People.from_dict(p)
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\dataclasses_json\api.py", line 83, in from_dict
    return _decode_dataclass(cls, kvs, infer_missing)
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\dataclasses_json\core.py", line 133, in _decode_dataclass
    overrides = _user_overrides_or_exts(cls)
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\dataclasses_json\core.py", line 59, in _user_overrides_or_exts
    if field.type in encoders:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Glasses'
```

I found that I can add (eq=True, frozen=True)
So I change my code to

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class Glasses:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int

@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class Tshirt:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class People:
    Name : str = 'James'
    Age : int = 25
    Glasses: Glasses = Glasses('black', 'M', 2500)
    Tshirt: Tshirt = Tshirt('black', 'XL', 500)

p = {
    'Name': 'Gino',
    'Age': 20,
    'Glasses': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    },
    'Tshirt': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    }
}

a = People.from_dict(p)
print(a)
```

And I got the other error

```
  File ".\People.py", line 39, in <module>
    a = People.from_dict(p)
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\dataclasses_json\api.py", line 83, in from_dict
    return _decode_dataclass(cls, kvs, infer_missing)
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\dataclasses_json\core.py", line 198, in _decode_dataclass
    infer_missing)
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\dataclasses_json\core.py", line 131, in _decode_dataclass
    if isinstance(kvs, cls):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Is there any possible way to fit my requirement using built-in functions without coding it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have field name and type name collision. In order for your code to work you must have JSON fields named differently from classes names, i.e. you can't have field `"Glasses"` and class `Glasses`, you must rename class to something like `Glasses_` or rename your fields names.

Another option is to create alias for classes types, i.e. create alias `GlassesT` to `Glasses`.

Version of code with type aliases:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64565379var2#main.py)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass
class Glasses:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int

GlassesT = Glasses

@dataclass
class Tshirt:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int
    
TshirtT = Tshirt
    
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class People:
    Name : str = 'James'
    Age : int = 25
    Glasses: GlassesT = GlassesT('black', 'M', 2500)
    Tshirt: TshirtT = TshirtT('black', 'XL', 500)

p = {
    'Name': 'Gino',
    'Age': 20,
    'Glasses': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    },
    'Tshirt': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    }
}

a = People.from_dict(p)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
People(Name='Gino', Age=20, Glasses=Glasses(color='red', size='M', prize=4000), Tshirt=Tshirt(color='red', size='M', prize=4000))
```

Version of code with renamed classes:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64565379#main.py)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass
class Glasses_:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int

@dataclass
class Tshirt_:
    color: str
    size: str
    prize: int

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class People:
    Name : str = 'James'
    Age : int = 25
    Glasses: Glasses_ = Glasses_('black', 'M', 2500)
    Tshirt: Tshirt_ = Tshirt_('black', 'XL', 500)

p = {
    'Name': 'Gino',
    'Age': 20,
    'Glasses': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    },
    'Tshirt': {
        'color' : 'red',
        'size' : 'M',
        'prize' : 4000
    }
}

a = People.from_dict(p)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
People(Name='Gino', Age=20, Glasses=Glasses_(color='red', size='M', prize=4000), Tshirt=Tshirt_(color='red', size='M', prize=4000))
```

Comment: Oh, this is awesome ! this really helps me ! thanks